# How to user bold in custom command?

Tags: macros, bold

I would like to highlight some text in my paper as "programming code" with Courier font family and I found this solution.

```
\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}
\newenvironment{kod}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}{\par}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\kod}{\myfont}
```

but I would like to have a selection bold, use `\textbf{}` command. Where should I place this command into my `\kod` command?

Comment: Write `\bfseries` instead of `\selectfont`

Comment: do you want all monospace text to use Courier, if so just use `\renewcommand\ttdefault{pcr}` then you can use `\ttfamily\bfseries`

Comment: If you have a lot of code throughout your document you really should look at the `listings` package.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, either you define a `kod` environment or a `\kod` command taking an argument with `\DeclareTextFontCommand`

You can surely select boldface by adding the declaration `\bfseries`; using the command defined beforehand avoids code duplication. I leave a definition for the environment, but I don't think it's useful.

```
\newcommand{\kodfont}{%
  \fontfamily{pcr}\bfseries % \selectfont is implied by \bfseries
}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\kod}{\kodfont}
\newenvironment{kodenv}
 {\par\kodfont}
 {\par}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\kodfont}{%
  \fontfamily{pcr}\bfseries % \selectfont is implied by \bfseries
}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\kod}{\kodfont}

\newenvironment{kodenv}
 {\par\kodfont}
 {\par}

\begin{document}

Some text and \kod{code in bold face Courier} with other text.

\end{document}
```

[image]