# Text in custom command overflows the page

Tags: macros

This text is connected to solution described in this question: [How to user bold in custom command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238563/how-to-user-bold-in-custom-command)

When I use this custom command:

```
\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{pcr}\bfseries}
\newenvironment{kod}{\fontfamily{pcr}\bfseries}{\par}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\kod}{\myfont}
```

sometime my text overflows the page, as you can see on this image:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's quite complicated because this is a school thesis template with some additional files. Should I send all?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be reasonable. Try to isolate the problem, first.

Answer (score 2):

Like most monospace fonts hyphenation is disabled by default for `pcr` the file `ot1pcr.fd` has

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pcr}{\hyphenchar \font\m@ne}
```

where `\m@ne` is -1 and means there is no hyphenation char.

You could put

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pcr}{\hyphenchar`\-}
```

to reset it to normal (or the same with T1 if you use T1 encoding)

but on the other hand they look like class and function names and perhaps you don't want them breaking with `-` over the line. If you do not you have to say what you do want to happen, you could use `\sloppy` to allow white space to stretch or some other alternatives, depending on the effect you want.

Comment: `\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pcr}{\hyphenchar`\-}` didn't help. But I use UT-F8 encoding - `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` if I understand what you mean.

Comment: @user1315357 the input encoding such as UTF-8 is irrelevant here, what matters is the font encoding (which is usually T1 or OT1) This is why questions should _always_ have a _complete_ small document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that shows the problem. If you edit your question to add such a test file I will adjust the answer to fit it.

Comment: I'll try it, but there is some another template file (`*.cls`) so I will have to process it.

Comment: @user1315357 You should be able to make an example using `article.cls` if not then the problem is _just_ in the class file which we have not seen, in which case it is rather hard to help and then you definitely need to make an example by copying over enough lines from your custom class file that the problem occurs.